# Getting rid of %40 in search

Tags: php, mysql, search, urlencode

I'm trying to use this code to return the email address as a search keyword to pull up search result if it's searched for in a form.  But the keyword posts in the browser as user%40domain.com.  I need it to register as user@domain.com so the database mysql query can find it in the db.  here's the code right now and it doesn't work.

```
   if (isset($_GET['search']) && tep_not_null($_GET['search'])) {
      $keywords = tep_db_input(tep_db_prepare_input($_GET['search']));
      $search = "where c.customers_lastname like '%" . $keywords . "%' or c.customers_email_address like '%" . urlencode($keywords) . "%'";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

%40 is equivalent to @. It gets converted because you use `urlencode()`. If you want to convert it back before displaying it to the page, then to the opposite and use `urldecode()`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Or, you know, just not do it in the first place.

Comment: yea yea, but who knows, perhaps the asker had a reason to do so? I am not one to judge, but I'm with you on this one LOL

Answer (score 0):

Both [John](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11515435/377270) and [TurdPile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11515434/377270) have the essential answer -- use `urldecode()` -- but they miss a *vital* point -- you have done all your input sanitizing on the input directly from the user. If you are going to provide URL-decoding in this routine, **you must perform the input sanitizing after decoding the input**. Otherwise, input that sanitizes correctly and is then URL-decoded could introduce an [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Switch to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to avoid having to think about input sanitizing -- just use parameterized statements correctly and you will not write programs vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: You're mostly right, except for two points: 1) the OP is using some DB abstraction library that we know nothing about, and 2) the OP is actually *encoding* the input.

Comment: Got it figured out.  I didn't have to do anything.  Sorry!

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Both good points. I made the assumption that the combination `tep_db_input(tb_dp_prepare_input())` was responsible for the input sanitizing. I also made the assumption that `urlencode()` in this instance was a _mistake_. Thanks for raising the complaints. :)